# How to modify the array value based on another variable in SAS?

Tags: arrays, variables, sas

```
data tempx1;
  input ID;
  cards;
  1
  2
  3
  4
  ;
run;

data tempx2;
   set tempx1;
   array diag{4} d1 d2 d3 d4 (1,2,3,4);
     do i = 1 to 4;
      if diag[i] = ID then diag[i] = 1; else diag[i] = 0;
     end;
    drop i;
run;
```

I want 1's to be in the diagonal of the array, what did i do wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you initialise an array with a set of values, the values you give it are only set once.  They don't get re-set for each implicit loop of the dataset.

You therefore must do this explicitly.  The following code will work for you:

```
data tempx2;
set tempx1;
array diag{4} d1 d2 d3 d4 (1,2,3,4);

do i = 1 to 4;
diag[i] = i;
end;

do i = 1 to 4;
if diag[i] = ID then diag[i] = 1; else diag[i] = 0;
end;

drop i;

run;
```

Here is a demo which should make it easier to understand why this works:

```
data test;
set tempx1;
array diag{4} d1 d2 d3 d4 (1,2,3,4);
put _all_;
output;
if _n_ = 1 then diag{1} = 10;
if _n_ = 3 then diag{1} =  20;
put _all_;
output;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt help! Though I have oversimplified my question, what you said that the initial values are only set once makes sense. my initial values are not actually a good boy like 1,2,3, but rather some irregular numbers or strings, so I create a macro variable and set the value of diag[i] first using code similar to what you have added, and then do the comparison. Problem solved! The lesson here is all about initial values setting up only once!!thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a simpler solution, because you really aren't trying to use the initialized values.  You're just not doing the proper comparison.  Compare to i, don't compare to diag[i].

```
data tempx2;
   set tempx1;
   array diag{4} d1 d2 d3 d4 (1,2,3,4);
     do i = 1 to 4;
      if i = ID then diag[i] = 1; else diag[i] = 0;
     end;
    drop i;
run;
```

Comment: thanks for your help! it's a sweet solution. However because I oversimplified my question, directly comparing i to ID is not as general as setting the values as solution provide by RobinL, so I marked the first solution!Thanks again!